# Possible reasons for changing P value significance after adjusting other covariate in a multiple regression?

Tags: r, regression, p-value, multicollinearity, confounding

Take any multiple regression model as an example, p value change from significant to non-significant or the opposite, after adjusting for one or several covariates in the model. My statistical teacher said the reason is because of potential collinearity, which is discussed quite often among people. But there could be other factors such as negative confounder, etc. Above all, I would like a good summary of the causes of changes in significance tests for individual predictors in multiple regression models, preferably illustrating with an example performed in R. For instance, simulating some data for each of reason, etc. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The significance of the model is not affected by collinearity except in the trivial sense that adding redundant variables will increase the df numerator (and decrease df denominator) without increasing the SSQ numerator or decreasing the SSQ denominator appreciably. For individual predictiors, collinearity means confounded variance and when variance is confounded it is difficult to reach strong conclusions about individual effects. Mathematically, this is reflected in the standard errors of the regression weights (they will be high with collinearity).

Comment: My question is about the significance  change occurring for some covariates in the model after adding other covariates, rather than the significance of the whole model. But your illustration about the collinearity itself is good, although it is not what I'm asking for.

Comment: Thanks. I think my last two sentences address this although I don't use the word "significance."

Comment: May I ask will the the significance's change of covariate (named X1) after adding one covariate (named X2) in the model might be possibly caused by "confounding" issue, besides collinearity?  Say, the X2 has no 'collinearity" with the  X1, but X2 is a strong cofounder for relationship between X1 and dependent variable.

Comment: In short, the better the prediction of X1 from all other predictors including X2, the higher will be the standard error of b1 and the higher the associated p value. Generally speaking, if X1 and X2 are not correlated, adding X2 does not affect the predictability of X1 but there are patterns (e. g., suppression) when it does.